# Computing permutations with the Heap Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, elisp, heaps-algorithm

I am using the following the Heap Algorithm for computing permutation of words in elisp, but the permutations are not correct.

The problem could be associated with the way I use the two calls to `permute-strg-heap`.
I am quite sure that I have to call `(copy-sequence strg)` rather than `strg` so there will be no conflicts.

```
(defun permute-strg-heap (strg h &optional result)
  "Generate all permutations of string STRG using recursive
backtracking."

  (if (null result) (setq result '()))

  (if (= h 1)

      (progn
        (push strg result)  ; Output the permutation
        (message "%s" strg))

    (setq result
      (permute-strg-heap (copy-sequence strg) (1- h) result))

    ;; Generate permutations for j-th swapped with each j-1 initial
    (let ( (j 0) )
      (while (< j h)

        ;; Swap choice based upon h (even or odd)
        (if (evenp h)
            (swap-chars strg j (1- h))
          (swap-chars strg 0 (1- h)))

        (setq result
          (permute-strg-heap (copy-sequence strg) (1- h) result))

        (setq j (1+ j)))))

  result)
```

This is what I am trying to replicate

```
procedure generate(k : integer, A : array of any):
    if k = 1 then
        output(A)
    else
        // Generate permutations with k-th unaltered
        // Initially k = length(A)
        generate(k - 1, A)

        // Generate permutations for k-th swapped with each k-1 initial
        for i := 0; i < k-1; i += 1 do
            // Swap choice dependent on parity of k (even or odd)
            if k is even then
                swap(A[i], A[k-1]) // zero-indexed, the k-th is at k-1
            else
                swap(A[0], A[k-1])
            end if
            generate(k - 1, A)
        end for
    end if
```

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://superuser.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Was instructed it is the right place.  What would be right place for algorithms?

Comment: Right Right.....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating permutations with heap algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76815319/generating-permutations-with-heap-algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

`(while (< j h) ...)` should be `(while (< j (1- h)) ...)`.

It works when you change that. When debugging recursive functions, it helps to trace their invocations with `trace-function`.

```
(trace-function #'permute-strg-heap)
```

Wrong version with `(while (< j h) ...)`

```
1 -> (permute-strg-heap "ab" 2)
| 2 -> (permute-strg-heap "ab" 1 nil)
| 2 <- permute-strg-heap: ("ab")
| 2 -> (permute-strg-heap "ba" 1 ("ab"))
| 2 <- permute-strg-heap: ("ba" "ab")
| 2 -> (permute-strg-heap "ba" 1 ("ba" "ab"))
| 2 <- permute-strg-heap: ("ba" "ba" "ab")
1 <- permute-strg-heap: ("ba" "ba" "ab")
```

Correct version with `(while (< j (1- h)) ...)`

```
1 -> (permute-strg-heap "ab" 2)
| 2 -> (permute-strg-heap "ab" 1 nil)
| 2 <- permute-strg-heap: ("ab")
| 2 -> (permute-strg-heap "ba" 1 ("ab"))
| 2 <- permute-strg-heap: ("ba" "ab")
1 <- permute-strg-heap: ("ba" "ab")
```